# Could not cast value of type 'ProjectName.AddNewPropery' (0x10fa2edf0) to 'ProjectName.ViewProfile' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting crash while pushing view controller in action method i used this code

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addProperty") as! ViewProfile
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. i missed "AddNewPropery" class name of second view controller. replacing "ViewProfile" to "AddNewPropery" fixed my problem.

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addProperty") as! AddNewPropery
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```